# Do matches from the CONMEBOL–UEFA Cup of Champions count for the FIFA ranking?

Tags: football, ranking, fifa

I was watching a Youtube video where a non professional soccer commentator stated that the [CONMEBOL–UEFA Cup of Champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CONMEBOL%E2%80%93UEFA_Cup_of_Champions) is "not considered official by FIFA", whatever that meant to him. Sure the match isn't organized by FIFA, but other matches not organized by FIFA such as Copa America matches or CONMEBOL world cup qualifiers aren't organized by FIFA either, but they count for the [FIFA ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_Men%27s_World_Ranking) which serves for organizing the world cup groups, so they are recognized by FIFA in a way. So I wondered if the matches from the CONMEBOL–UEFA Cup of Champions count for the FIFA ranking. Do they? That would show if they are recognized by FIFA or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES** the game did contribute to the FIFA ranking. It met the requirements for a contributing friendly game during International Match Calendar windows.

Friendly games are taken into account for the FIFA ranking, although with less importance when calculating the points. A smaller weight is used for a friendly compared to a tournament qualifying game.

> P = Pbefore + I * (W – We)
> Pbefore: Points before the match
>
> *I: importance of match*
>
> - I= 05 Friendly matches played outside of International Match Calendar windows
> - I= 10 Friendly matches played during International Match Calendar windows
> - I= 15 Group phase matches of Nations League competitions
> - I= 25 Play-off and final matches of Nations League competitions
> - I= 25 Qualification matches for Confederations final competitions and for FIFA World Cup final
>   competitions
> - I= 35 Confederation final competition matches up until the QF stage
> - I= 40 Confederation final competition matches from the QF stage onwards; all FIFA Confederations Cup matches
> - I= 50 FIFA World Cup final competition matches up until QF stage
> - I= 60 FIFA World Cup final competition matches from QF stage onwards

> source: https://digitalhub.fifa.com/m/f99da4f73212220/original/edbm045h0udbwkqew35a-pdf.pdf

If you check the June 2022 update on https://www.fifa.com/fifa-world-ranking/men?dateId=id13687 you see a difference for Argentina of +5.52 points.

The Italy-Argentina match is referenced on this website dedicated to tracking the FIFA ranking and contributing games: https://football-ranking.com/fifa-world-matchs?period=23%20June%202022&tournament=

Here you can find the points gained from the Italy-Argentina (+4.6) game and Estonia-Argentina (+0.92) that were played in June 2022. Totaling to the +5.52 difference on the FIFA Ranking points.

Comment: So any friendly game counts for the FIFA ranking, the only difference it's in ponts if the friendly game was scheduled by FIFA or not?

Comment: FIFA does not schedule friendlies, but it has some requirements for them to count (at least in the past). Such as a maximum number of substitutes.
The FA's arrange their own friendlies and are thus free to choose their opponents.

Comment: The only thing I can find about it is this: http://www.football-rankings.info/2012/11/fifa-ranking-rules-for-friendly-matches.html But it dates from 2012